# How to use output buffering control?

Tags: python, python-3.x, controls, buffer

I need to save output in Python.

**Example:**

```
import os

ob_start();
os.system( 'c:\files\file.exe' );
var = ob_content();
ob_close();
print "message:\n\t" + var
```

Comment: Do you mean the output if file.exe? Then probably subprocess can help: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: no need to use semicolons (`;`) after each line in Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module and pass `stdout` and `stderr` via pipes back to your calling process using a `Popen` object (make sure to read the docs on which convenience methods you should not use with pipes on `stdout` or `stderr`). `os.system` is a pretty one-dimensional hammer, and while easy to use simply won't do what you want.